# How to find middle point between 2 pulses in Verilog in an FPGA?

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdmi

I'm trying to find the mid-point between hsync pulses in a video stream. There are many "pixel clocks" in between hsync pulses. How can I get a pulse or signal exactly at the midpoint between two hsync pulses? Basically I want to be able to find the horizontal center of the screen. Here is what I have:

```
reg [30:0] count;
reg [30:0] counter;
wire left;

always @(posedge pixclk)
    begin
        if (hsync == 1'b1)
        begin
            count = counter;
            counter = 1'b0;
        end
        else
        begin
            counter = counter + 1;
        end
    end

assign left = (counter < (count / 2) ? 1'b1 : 1'b0);
```

First, I don't know if this is conceptually the right way to do this.
Second, if `hsync` is held low for more than one `pixclk` cycle, then count will always be zero. It will only work if the width of `hsync` pulse is exactly one clock cycle or less.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First: You should use non-blocking assignments in a clocked section. `<=`

In your case you tell me that you have an hsync which is longer then your pixel clock. 
One way is to count pulses when the hsync is low and store the result when it is high. That would require a small two-state Fine-State-Machine (FSM)

However I personally find making Fine-State-Machines a burden to be avoided. So here is what I would do:
Detect the edge of the hysnc (when it goes high or when it goes low) and count between the edges. Here is the core of the code:

```
reg hsync_one_cycle_delayed;

always @(posedge pixclk)
begin
    hsync_one_cycle_delayed <= hsync;

    if (hsync==1'b1 && hsync_one_cycle_delayed==1'b0)
    // We have a detected a rising edge on hsync
    begin
        count <= counter;
        counter <= 31'h0;
    end
    else
        counter <= counter + 1;
end
```

Some final notes:

- It assume the hsync is synchronous to the pixel clock.
- This code has no reset which seems to become the norm in FPGA code, but which I personally deplore.